# Center align Foundation 6 Dropdown

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm trying to show a horizontally center-aligned Foundation 6 dropdown. I'm attempting to use a dropdown as a tooltip, because it better fits my needs and allows for rich HTML to be inserted into it, where the tooltip does not.

Foundation 6 dropdowns can be positioned by adding classes `.top .right .bottom .left`. These classes are parsed by the Foundation core Javascript and then the element is given dynamically calculated `top:` and `left:` attributes.

Because of this, adding any `left`, or `transform: translate` properties to the element are voided by the fact that Foundation takes this into account when dynamically calculating the positioning attributes.

Any ideas short of writing a different class into the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-center`.

```
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <ul class="menu text-center">
                <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1b</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1c</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```